# Flutter can't pass optional Route Argument

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-routes

I am trying to pass an object as a route argument in Flutter. For this I use `ModalRoute.of(context as BuildContext)!.settings.arguments as Object?;` . This object should be optional. Therefore I have made it nullable. (Object?) After reading it should be decided whether it is present or not and acted accordingly. if this object is not present, I get an error called: `Bad state: No element`
This cannot be intercepted with a try catch. what am I doing wrong?

```
late Object? editObject;
bool edited = false;
bool loaded = false;

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   if (!loaded) {
     loaded = true;
     editRecipe =
     ModalRoute
         .of(context as BuildContext)!
         .settings
         .arguments as Object?;
     if (editObject != null) {
       edited = true;
       //filling in the info into the ui
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to first check if `ModalRoute.of(context)` is `null` **before** trying to access it's `settings.arguments`. Soemething like this:

```dart
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final route = ModalRoute.of(context);
    
    if (route != null) {
      final args = route.settings.arguments;
      if (args != null) {
        editObject = args;
        edited = true;
      }
    }
```

Or, instead, you can probably even use `?` instead of `!`:

```dart
final routeArgs = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments;
```